# Navbar CSS conflicts with bootstrap CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I copied the "mega menu" navbar from W3Schools to a blank page and attached custom CSS, but as soon as I attach the bootstrap CSS file, the header layout is changed completely and the dropdown content doesn't show up anymore. I added two images below the snippet to show what exactly happens. I tried finding the CSS conflict with element inspector without success. I also tried different versions of bootstrap.css but all versions are causing the same navbar to become misplaced.

```css
/* HEADER CSS */

/* Custom */
.navbar {
 height:100px!important;
 border-bottom:5px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)!important;
 font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif"!important;
}
.brand {
 margin-top:9px!important;
 width:175px!important;
}
.brand-link {
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.00)!important;
}
.brand-link:hover {
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.00)!important;
}
.navlink {
 margin-top:45px!important;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)!important;
 color:rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
 font-size:1.10em!important;
 font-weight:300!important;
}
.navlink:hover {
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)!important;
 color:rgba(55,175,75,0.35)!important;
}
.droplink {
 
}
.droplink:hover {
 
}
.dropbtn {
 margin-top:45px!important;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)!important;
 color:rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
 cursor:pointer!important;
 font-size:1.10em!important;
 font-weight:300!important;
}
.dropdown-content {
 margin-top:-2px!important;
 background-color:rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
}
.dropdown-content .header {
 background-color:rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
}
.dropdown-content .header-title {
 margin-top:0!important;
 margin-bottom:8px!important;
 color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)!important;
 font-size:1.35em!important;
}
.dropdown-content .droprow {
 background-color:rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
}
.dropdown-content .dropcol {
 background-color:rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
}

/* Default */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Naamloos document</title><h3></h3>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
 
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="/index.htm" class="brand-link">
 <img src="/img/brand.png" class="responsive brand" alt="navbar brand icon">
  </a>
  <a href="#home" class="navlink">Home</a>
  <a href="#news" class="navlink">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2 class="header-title">Mega Menu</h2>
      </div>   
      <div class="row droprow">
        <div class="column dropcol">
          <h3 class="header-title">Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column dropcol">
          <h3 class="header-title">Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column dropcol">
          <h3 class="header-title">Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column dropcol">
          <h3 class="header-title">Category 4</h3>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="droplink">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Without any bootstrap CSS file attached (blue area is image), while mouse over dropdown button!**

[image: mega menu without bootstrap.css]

**With bootstrap CSS file attached (blue area is image), also while mouse over dropdown button!**

[image: mega menu with bootstrap.css]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

I completely removed the .navbar class and all corresponding CSS classes from the bootstrap.css file **and replaced it** with the W3Schools navbar CSS.

As this is a testing site I can do this, but I would not recommend it as a definitive solution. It may cause problems later (I haven't experienced any so far).

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/
Try Bootstrap 3 and check if that still happens to you.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 causes the same problem but with a different layout.